# Dynamics 365: Using createdon Date in the OData $filter is giving "UserId is empty guid"! error

Tags: filter, odata

I am using the following OData query in the POST man and is giving the error i.e.

The below query works fine i.e.
http:///api/data/v9.0/ngt_assignments(173554B4-A103-EC11-8117-005056814F19)?$select=ngt_assignmentid, createdon

But when I use the following in $filter query i.e. and%20createdon%20ge%202022-02-21 filter as per below Url i.e.

http:///api/data/v9.0/ngt_assignments(173554B4-A103-EC11-8117-005056814F19)?$select=ngt_assignmentid, createdon&$filter=createdon%20ge%202022-02-21

Then, I got the following error i.e.

"error": {
"code": "0x80040217",
"message": "UserId is empty guid! ",
"innererror": {
"message": "UserId is empty guid! ",
"type": "Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmObjectNotFoundException",
"stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.UserDataCacheLoader.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0()\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)\r\n   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.ObjectModelCacheLoader`2.LoadCacheDataInternal(TKey key, Object existingDataContainer, IOrganizationContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.ObjectModelCacheLoader`2.LoadCacheData(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmMultiOrgCacheBase`2.CreateEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmMultiOrgCacheBase`2.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.b__2()\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Action action)\r\n   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Action action)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmMultiOrgCacheBase`2.LookupEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmDateTimeBuilderBase.ConvertUtcTimeToUserTime(DateTime utcTime, IUserAndOrganizationContext userAndOrganizationContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.DynamicCrmDateTimeBuilder.ConvertToCrmDateTime(DateTime dateTime, IUserAndOrganizationContext userAndOrganizationContext, DateTimeToCrmDateTimeConversionStrategy strategy)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Query.DateTimeConditionParser.GetCrmDateTime(AttributeMetadata attribute, Object value, IUserAndOrganizationContext userAndOrganizationContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Query.ConditionExpression..ctor(AttributeMetadata attribute, ConditionOperator conditionOperator, Array values, Boolean isCustom, IUserAndOrganizationContext userAndOrganizationContext, DynamicMetadataCache cache)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.DataQueryOptionsConverter.GetConditionExpression(Object leftVal, BinaryOperatorNode node, Object rightVal, Boolean negateOperator)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.DataQueryOptionsConverter.BindBinaryOperatorNode(BinaryOperatorNode binaryOperatorNode, FilterExpression parentFilter, Boolean negateOperator)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.QueryOptionsConverterBase`4.Bind(QueryNode node, TFilterExpression parentFilter, Boolean negateOperator, XrmMetadataEntityMetadata metadata)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.DataQueryOptionsConverter.BindBinaryOperatorNode(BinaryOperatorNode binaryOperatorNode, FilterExpression parentFilter, Boolean negateOperator)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.QueryOptionsConverterBase`4.Bind(QueryNode node, TFilterExpression parentFilter, Boolean negateOperator, XrmMetadataEntityMetadata metadata)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.QueryOptionsConverterBase`4.BindFilterClause(FilterClause filterClause, XrmMetadataEntityMetadata metadata, Object[] args)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.DataQueryOptionsConverter.SetFilterExpression(EntityExpression qe, FilterQueryOption filterQueryOption, XrmMetadataEntityMetadata metadata)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.QueryOptionsConverterBase`4.GetQueryExpression(ODataQueryOptions queryOptions, String edmEntityName, CrmODataExecutionContext context, XrmMetadataEntityMetadata metadata)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataServiceDataProvider.RetrieveEdmEntity(CrmODataExecutionContext context, String edmEntityName, String entityKeyValue, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.EntityController.GetEntityImplementation(String& entityName, String key)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)\r\n   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"
}
}
}

Quick help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the question at Dynamics Community and got the clue from one of the member. For above question, please check the details at https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/462500/dynamics-365-on-premises-using-createdon-date-in-the-odata-filter-is-giving-userid-is-empty-guid-error/1267182